# How to find duplicates in mongoDB with two conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I want to find duplicates in the MongoDB atlas. I have seen examples for finding duplicates but they didn't take two conditions as I understand it. for some network issues, we discovered duplicates with a reference(refno) number in the database

so I want to find duplicate refno within these two conditions (currentDate and transactionTypeId)

```
 const transactionRecord = await this.tranModel.aggregate(
[{ $group: 
      { _id: "$refno",  count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } }
])
```

With the above code I was able to get all the duplicates in the db, but I want to limit it to the condition

```
{ transactiontdate: currentDate, transactionTypeID: transactionTypesid });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working

```
 const Record = await this.tranModel.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: { transactiontdate: currentDate, transactionTypeID: transactionTypeID }
                    },
                    {
                        $group: { _id: "$refno", count: { $sum: 1 } }
                    }, {
                        $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } }
                    }
                ])
                if (Record != null) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < Record.length; i++) {
                        const element = Record[i]._id.toString()
                        tranArray.push(element)
                    }
                }
            }
```